# Angular: Child extends Parent Dependency Not Working

Tags: angularjs, service, ecmascript-6, extends, es6-class

I have a child service that I want to extend from a parent service using the `extends` keyword. I'm having some trouble injecting another service `MyService` into the child service.

```
export class ParentService {
  constructor($http) {}

  get() {
    this.$http.get('/someUrl').then(res => res.data);
  }
}

export class ChildService extends ParentService {
  constructor($http, private MyService) {
    super($http);
  }

  get() {
    const data = super.get();
    return this.MyService.cleanData(data);
  }
}
```

For some reason `MyService` is coming back as `undefined` in the `ChildService`, and I can only assume something is going wrong with the DI. If I remove the `extends` keyword however, `MyService` works as expected.

Any idea what might be going on here. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you using @Inject on above of classes ?

Comment: @HasanBeheshti No, I'm not using Inject. I'm using Angular 1.5.

Comment: _" I'm using Angular 1.5"_ Then don't use the angular tag, please.

Answer (score 0):

Try renaming the `get()` methods within the `ParentService` and `ChildService` to anything else.

`get` is a keyword/binding-syntax that binds an object property to a function that is called when that property is looked up. The compiler is expecting a property or function name after the `get` and may be getting tripped up. Even in Plunkr `get` is highlighted by the IDE indicating a reserved word/syntax.

`get` could be used like this with ES6 classes:

```
class Todo {
    constructor(task) {
        this.task = task;
    }

    get task() {
        return this.task.toUpperCase();
    }
}
```

> The [get](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) syntax binds an object property to a function that will be
>   called when that property is looked up.

Try changing `get` to `getData` or whatever you need.

```
export class ParentService {
  constructor($http) {}

  getData() {
    return this.$http.get('/someUrl');
  }
}

export class ChildService extends ParentService {
  constructor($http, private MyService) {
    super($http);
  }

  getData() {
    return super.getData()
        .then(data => this.MyService.cleanData(data))
        .catch(error => console.log(error));
  }
}
```

Here is a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/byyPWlfVUUeqhVih5uI9?p=preview) demonstrating the functionality at a very basic level including a `ParentService`, `ChildService`, and a `MyService`, with `MyService` being injected into `ChildService` and `ChildService` extending `ParentService`. A `console.log()` is being executed in this example within the `constructor()` of the child to show that DI is occurring properly.

Hopefully this helps!